# Parsing nested JSON string - type mismatch error

Tags: json, vba, excel

I'm trying to parse through a JSON string to extract one item, but having some trouble.

This is the JSON string I'm parsing through that I've stored in a variable called `result`:

```
{"From":{"Chocolate":{"Price":1.0,"AsAtDate":"2018-05-04T00:00:00"},"Lime":{"Price":1.35415115,"AsAtDate":"2018-05-04T00:00:00"},"Strawberry":{"Price":1.19517151,"AsAtDate":"2018-05-04T00:00:00"},"Vanilla":{"Price":0.77522986,"AsAtDate":"2018-05-04T00:00:00"},"Blueberry":{"Price":1.00084071,"AsAtDate":"2018-05-04T00:00:00"},"Lemon":{"Price":0.75030012,"AsAtDate":"2018-05-04T00:00:00"}},"To":"Chocolate","RequestedDate":"2018-05-22T08:26:16"}
```

All I'm trying to extract is the "Price". I was trying to run it through a for loop -

```
Dim result As String
Dim Item As Variant
Dim parsedResult As Object
Dim i As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet

result = objHTTP.responseText

Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set parsedResult = JsonConverter.ParseJson(result)

i = 1

For Each Item In parsedResult("From")
    ws.Cells(i, 2) = Item("Price")
    i = i + 1
Next
```

I continuously, continuously keep getting a `type mismatch` error at

> ws.Cells(i, 2) = Item("Price")

Is there anything I'm defining wrong here? I routed `result` to make sure I was getting the correct JSON string to parse (shown above), so everything up to that point is great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replacing your failing row with

```
ws.Cells(i, 2) = parsedResult("From")(Item)("Price")
```

Comment: You are my hero. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I know this is easily achieved by Json parser, but to demonstrate how to get results from nested dictionaries, please see the following:

```
Set dict1 = parsedResult
For Each Key1 In dict1
    Set dict2 = dict1("From")
    For Each Key2 In dict2
        Set dict3 = dict2(Key2)
        For Each Key3 In dict3
            Debug.Print dict3("Price")
        Next Key3
    Next Key2
Next Key1
```